# 3000+ reputation - what can I do now?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I would like to read the 3 paragraphs what I can do now after having achieved 3000+ reputation.
I was offered to read them as I reached 3k rep, but now I cannot find it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: First, congratulations. And the answer is, in short: you can start working on the "Close votes" queue. Which I'm finding rather depressing.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not too long ago, you can just open your achievements dialog (the trophy in the navigation bar) and click the notification about the new privilege:

[image]

This will take you to the link @DanielFischer provided in the comments: [cast close and reopen votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). @T.S' link (also accessible from the 'privileges' link in the top of the achievements dialog) is helpful if you want to see *all* privileges you earned/can earn.

Comment: The thing is that in that reference which "is not too long ago" in your words is not exactly all what I was reading at the time I was noticed that I reached 3k :-( It was something that I could "name the answers", I do not recall it perfectly though.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to check what one can do with certain amount of "reputations", see this page in the help center:

https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges